can't delete FullTextIndex from table
I recently migrated a SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012, then to SQL Server 2019. Now the database integrity check throws errors about the full text index files on two tables.
When I check the SQL Server 2019 database's file groups, I see there are 0 files in the ftfg_tablename's definition.
When I try to delete the full text index, I get this error. I have a hunch the full text index isn't working in the new version of SQL Server, so I'd like to start the full text index over. How can I delete the pointer to the missing full text index file, then create a new one, etc.

Drop failed for FullTextIndex 'PK_Comment'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
Failed to finish full-text operation. Filegroup 'ftfg_Comments' is empty, read-only, or not online. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 9964)


select data_space_id, is_read_only from sys.filegroups where name = 'ftfg_Comments' returns what? select name, data_space_id, state, is_read_only, is_media_read_only from sys.database_files where type_desc = 'FULLTEXT' returns what?

Both of these queries return 0 rows -- i.e., nothing.

The first query should certainly have returned something, unless you have the name wrong or connected to the wrong database. What about select c.name as catalog_name, d.name as filegroup_name, d.is_read_only, f.name as file_name, f.state, f.is_read_only as file_read_only, f.state from sys.fulltext_catalogs c left join sys.filegroups d on d.data_space_id = c.data_space_id left join sys.database_files f on f.file_id = c.file_id If that still doesn't return anything then I suggest you run DBCC CHECKDB because something is seriously wrong.
